# Relocate / Move elevation position in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, widget, material-design

#### Problem

---

The following image shows how normally the elevation is aligned for every Widget in Flutter (if elevation is available):

[image: elevation example]

But I want to move the elevation to the direct center (`Offset(0.0, 0.0)`) of the `Card` Widget here.

I never found a clean solution. Does anyone got an answer here?

Comment: Please share some code of what you've tried that can be edited to a answer.

Comment: if you mean that elevation shadow then it seems that the offsets are hardcoded, you would need for example `ShapeDecoration` where you can define your own shadows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `offset` of elevation is not possible in flutter. Flutter follows  [Material Design](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html) principles and the capability to modify parameters like offset would beat that purpose.

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/55289324c6d1db9071fb372f9f15f5ad5a064eeb/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/shadows.dart#L33) for shadows in flutter, elevation is nothing but a list of shadows. If you want to modify elevation parameters, I would suggest create a custom wrapper and use actual values with overridable parameter.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomElevation extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Offset offset;
  final int elevation;
  final Map<int, List<BoxShadow>> _elevationToShadow;

  CustomElevation({@required this.child, @required this.elevation, this.offset = const Offset(0.0, 0.0)})
      : assert(child != null),
        // Here kElevationToShadow is a map exposed by flutter material design shadows
        _elevationToShadow = kElevationToShadow.map<int, List<BoxShadow>>(
          (int key, List<BoxShadow> value) => MapEntry<int, List<BoxShadow>>(
            key,
            value.map(
              (BoxShadow bs) => BoxShadow(
                offset: offset,
                blurRadius: bs.blurRadius,
                spreadRadius: bs.spreadRadius,
                color: bs.color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: _elevationToShadow[elevation] ?? <BoxShadow>[],
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

or if you need something different altogether, go ahead and elevate as your heart desires :)

Comment: Thank you soo much @Vineet :). I'll give it a try. At least all of you guys brought me to the idea to use `BoxShadow`